# python import - import .json file from parent directory

Tags: python, import, python-import, python-module

I am attempting to import a config.json file into my python script. I have the following python script from a co-worker of mine that does stuff.:

**myscript.py**

```
import datetime
import sys
import json

from config import config
...
```

...and I have the following directory structure:

```
Project
 |
 +-- config
 |  |
 |  +-- config.json
 |    
 +-- scripts
 |  |  
 |  +-- myscript.py
```

I cannot change the directory structure, and I *shouldn't* change the import statement either, as this is actually a co-workers script that I need to run locally. When I run `python3 myscript.py`, I receive the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'config'
```

I am actually not surprised by the error, because I'm not setting a relative path to `config`. I feel like the import should be `from ../config import config`, however this is not how my co-worker did it. Also, `from ../config import config` did not work either.

How can I import `config.json` without changing the import statement or the directory structure? Perhaps I can add `/config` to my path?

Comment: why are You trying to **import** json file (is that even possible)? You can just open it using file path, also when it looks for modules it looks for `.py` files

Comment: config is a dictionary with a bunch of keys / passwords for our app. I agree that it could be opened using file path. I'm not certain as to why it's being done this way. I am simply trying to get the current script to run as is, and understand why it works for others, but not for me

Comment: This can't work because `config.json` isn't python. `from config import config` is looking for a python module inside a like named package "config". Things are only packages if the python importer thinks they are. The only way the orginal code works is if the "config" directory is resolved as a package in python. Either it was installed (do you have a setup.py somewhere) or something has added the "Project" path to the environment variable PYTHONPATH or to python's `sys.path`. This is all highly unusual. I thnik its up to your coworker to tell you how to do it.

Comment: Yeah I don't think this is possible, at least even my IDE threw an error at least while You try resolving this issue You can access it by file path

Comment: @tdelaney thank you so much - i think what may be happening, is that the `config/` directory is a directory that creates a python library `config`